# How do I create a paste chain using ifelse statements in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to generalize a snippet of code I have on processing raw ASCII data. In a nutshell: While the code does run, I have had to manually call every iteration of a paste function as long as an index condition is met, which does of course not allow for generalisations, a condition I need to satisfy. Below, you will find a simplified instance of my particular case:

Let `v_init` and `v_final` be index vectors:

```
  v_init <- c(1, 5, 6, 9, 11)
  v_final <- c(4, 5, 8, 10, 18)
```

For those index vectors, I would like to create a paste chain for groups of strings in `data`, i.e: Start iteration, paste strings 1, 2, 3, 4. End iteration. Start iteration, paste string 5. End iteration, etc.

The problem with doing it using `ifelse(...)` is that it only outputs scalar values, thus the j loop for every observation, but this comes in handy if I want to sample only a fragment of the rows. Furthermore, I have to state every index step in the paste function (`paste(data[i,j], ifelse(v_init[i] + 1 <= v_final[i],"data[i, j+1]", "", ifelse(v_init[i] + 2 <= v_final[i],"data[i, j+2]", "",` so on...)) whereas I would like for it to add another string while `v_init[i] + k <= v_final[i]` for all positive integer k's.

This is a simplified version of what I currently have:

```
  n <- 10
  s <- 500

  df <- data.frame()
    for (k in 1:n){
      for(j in 1:s){
        df[j,k] <- paste(noraw[j,v_init[k]], 
          ifelse(v_init[k]+1 <= v_final[k], data[j,v_init[k]+1], ""),
          ifelse(v_init[k]+2 <= v_final[k], data[j,v_init[k]+2], ""),
          ifelse(v_init[k]+3 <= v_final[k], data[j,v_init[k]+3], ""),
          ...
              sep = "")
          }
        }
```

As said, the code does run, however I cannot think of a way to compactify and generalize. Would it be possible to solve this, using a while loop for example? Also, I am aware that probably using ifelse's may not be the optimal way, I just could not come with any other.

Comment: Please supply your input data and your desired output.  Otherwise, your question is not self contained and you are far less likely to get the help you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `mapply`. You can give it two vectors and ask it to perform a function using the first element from each, then the second, and so on.

Suppose your character vector looked like this:

```
strings <- c("Four", "strings", "joined", "together", "Singleton", "Next", 
             "three", "strings", "Now", "two", "Finally", "a", 
             "larger", "sentence", "made", "from", "eight", "words")
```

And you have your two index vectors:

```
v_init <- c(1, 5, 6, 9, 11)
v_final <- c(4, 5, 8, 10, 18)
```

Now you can just call `mapply` like this:

```
mapply(function(x, y) paste(strings[x:y], collapse = " "), v_init, v_final)
#> [1] "Four strings joined together"                  
#> [2] "Singleton"                                     
#> [3] "Next three strings"                            
#> [4] "Now two"                                       
#> [5] "Finally a larger sentence made from eight words"
```